# Customer not storing in real time database in firebase but can be seen in authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Customer not storing in real time database in firebase but can be seen in authentication here below is my code please check what is wrong in my code

```
public class CustomerLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

   private EditText mEmail,mPassword;

   private Button mLogin,mRegisteration;

   private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
   private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if(user!=null){

                Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerLoginActivity.this,MapActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;

            }

        }
    };




    mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    mRegisteration = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registeration);

    mRegisteration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivity.this,"sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else{
                        String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Customers").child(user_id);
                        current_user_db.setValue(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


                    if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivity.this,"sign in error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
}
}
```

Customer not storing in real time database in firebase but can be seen in authentication here below is my code please check what is wrong in my code

Comment: The most common problem is that your user doesn't have permission to write to the database. If that is the case, you can find an error message about it in the logcat output of your app. Or you can add a completion callback: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback

Answer (score 0):

As @FrankvanPuffelen said, if everything you're doing is right, and still you can't see the data on Firebase database, then most probably you're missing out the data rules in your Firebase database.

This is what no security, read write allowed rules look like for Firebase:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

By default Firebase rules are set to this:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

This following is the set of rules for only authenticated user being able to write/read from database:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

You can read more about [rules in Firebase database here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiL3diw2svfAhVHL1AKHcn3DT4QFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fdatabase%2Fsecurity%2F&usg=AOvVaw3EEDwqrrKCEtcrX70LKKQd).

[Here is the list of set of rules for different purposes in Firebase database](https://gist.github.com/Pradyuman7/bb3b075cc82bdd3c59374aa257c37097).